# Is it possible to add an overlay to iOS home screen?

Tags: ios

So this is a hypothetical question. Is it possible to make an application that would run in the background and add a color overlay or filter to the actual iOS home screen? Does iOS allow for such applications?

If so, where could I find documentation on how to do something like that?

Comment: Can't be done (at least for an App Store app).

Comment: @rmaddy I see, thanks a lot.